# How to change the selected background color with the same opacity on MaterialButtonToggleGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, material-ui, material-components-android

Here is the XML code of My MaterialButtonToggleGroup

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/type_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/welcome_text"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/total_silence_button"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/total_silence"
            android:textColor="@color/light_green_700"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:rippleColor="@color/light_green_700"
            app:strokeColor="@color/light_green_700" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/priority_only_button"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/priority_only"
            android:textColor="@color/light_green_700"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:rippleColor="@color/light_green_700"
            app:strokeColor="@color/light_green_700" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/calls_only_button"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundTint="@color/light_green_700"
            android:text="@string/calls_only"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:iconTint="@color/light_green_700"
            app:rippleColor="@color/light_green_700" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

And the output is [image: Output].
When I select a button, the background color by default is [image: Output when selected]

My question is how to change the purple(ish) color with the same opacity?

Note:
I couldn't find any attribute to change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected background color with a M3 theme is defined by the **`colorSecondaryContainer`** attribute.

You can override it using:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/type_toggle"
        app:materialThemeOverlay="@style/button_overlay"
```

with:

```
    <style name="button_overlay" >
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">#ffe6e1e5</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can define a custom style for each Button usign:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/priority_only_button"
        style="@style/App.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton"
```

with:

```
<style name="App.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/app_m3_text_button_background_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

where the selector is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- selected color -->
    <item android:color="@color/teal_200" android:alpha="0.12"
        android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:color="?attr/colorContainer"/>
</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: Can one produce same result just by setting appropriate colors in theme.xml?